# Check which range the value belongs to and replace it with the midpoint of another vector in R

Tags: r, vector, range

I have three vectors

The first vector contains my values as follows

```
my_val <- c(0.61, 0.254, 0.5545, 0.47897)
```

The second vector start from zero and ends with 1

```
vec1 <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.25)
```

The third vector is the midpoint of `vec1` as

```
vec2 <-  zoo::rollmean(vec1, 2)
```

I want to check for each value in `my_val` in which range of `vec1` it lies and then replace it by the corresponding midpoint of that `vec1`, which is `vec2` indeed.

Here, I do it manually as follows:

```
ifelse(0.61 >=0 & 0.61 <=  0.25, 0.125, ifelse(0.61 >=0.25 & 0.61 <=  0.5, 0.375, ifelse(0.61 >=0.5 & 0.61 <=  0.75, 0.625, 0.875)
```

and keep doing the same for other values of `my_val`

Note that the actual length of `my_val` is 8000 and the step in `vec1` is 0.01667

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cut` you could do:

```r
my_val <- c(0.61, 0.254, 0.5545, 0.47897)  
vec1 <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.25)
vec2 <-  zoo::rollmean(vec1, 2)

vec2[cut(my_val, breaks = vec1, labels = FALSE)]
#> [1] 0.625 0.375 0.625 0.375
```